# Error in trying to add dependency for google_fonts in flutter project

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, crud, google-fonts

I'm getting this error. Please help.

Because google_fonts >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on crypto ^3.0.0 and uuid 2.2.2 depends on crypto ^2.0.0, google_fonts >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 is incompatible with uuid 2.2.2.
And because no versions of uuid match >2.2.2 <3.0.0, google_fonts >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 is incompatible with uuid ^2.2.2.
So, because flutter_firebase_login depends on both uuid ^2.2.2 and google_fonts ^2.1.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_firebase_login depends on both uuid ^2.2.2 and google_fonts ^2.1.0, version solving failed.)

I'm trying to add the dependency of google_fonts to my flutter project and facing this issue. Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your "uuid" package to some null safety version or you can use older versions of "google_fonts". If you want to update "uuid" you can use `^3.0.4` or if you want to use older "google_fonts" version you can use `^1.1.2` version.

Comment: I see let me try this. Will get back to you. thanks